# How do I temporarily set the decimal separator in C/C++?

Tags: c, visual-c++, io, internationalization, locale

I have some legacy C code that stores some numbers in a file, using the system locale. This causes a problem when the file is written in one locale (e.g. German, where a decimal separator is a comma) and then read in another (e.g. English, where the separator is a full-stop).

To avoid "2.5" in English being truncated to "2.0" in German (which is expecting "2,5"), I figured I would save the active locale name into the file, and set this as the active locale temporarily just for reading the file using setlocale(). The problem with this is that the decimal separator can be overwritten in Windows so it doesn't match the locale. For example, a user using "en-UK" locale might use a comma as a decimal separator. So I considered just saving the decimal separator character rather than the active locale name.

However, I can't seem to find a way to temporarily change the decimal separator in Windows just for reading the one file. SetLocaleInfo() doesn't seem to be the right answer, as it globally changes the Windows settings, which is not what I want -- I just want my program to change the way it reads number strings while reading in an external file.

I know I can use imbue() on an iostream to keep my changes local to my app, but my code is all legacy C and I want to avoid having to rewrite all of it to use C++ streams instead of the C stdio library. I can use localeconv() to get the decimal separator char, but I can't see a function that actually sets this rather than just reads it.

Is this possible in C? It seems like this should be a very common problem for anyone doing internationalisation, yet I haven't found a practical solution. Is there a better solution than rewriting all of my legacy C code into C++ and using streams and imbue?

Comment: What function does the "legacy C code" use to read in the values? If it's `fgets()` you can transcribe the string to another buffer doing character substitution on-the-fly before using `atof()` (or equivalent) on isolated bits of the buffer.

Comment: Currently atof() is what I use, which does observe the active locale. I guess manually substituting the decimal char is an option, didn't think of that. I'm just nervous there will be other language discrepancies I haven't counted on beyond simply the decimal separator.

Comment: Nothing for it but to go ahead and do it, and see what results. You don't need to transcribe (my previous comment). If source data is German, then just sweep through replacing comma with full stop, and vice versa... Hope your data doesn't have "thousands separators"... That could get tricky. (Still opposites, but a pain and I don't know if `atof()` would be happy either.) What have you got to lose by trying and seeing the results?

Comment: Ideally, when you have a data file that's both written and read by computer programs, you define the file format completely, so that it's not dependent on circumstances like word size, endianness, or locale.  Is the goal here that the data file also be easily readable by humans, such that using a locale-dependent format is appropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a "string" with some floating point numbers using "German convention" of the 'decimal point'
and "99.99" as the standard "full stop" as a a decimal point (mixed together).

The string is segmented (semi-colon field separators) and each segment first passes through a function to replace commas with full stops.
The resulting string goes straight to `atof()` and the floating point value printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *fix( char *str ) {
    for( char *cp = str; *cp; cp++ ) if( *cp == ',' ) *cp = '.';
    return str;
}

int main() {
    char buf[] = "125,45;987,65;100,00;99.99";

    for( char *cp = buf; (cp = strtok( cp, ";" ) ) != NULL; cp = NULL)
        printf( "%.2lf\n", atof( fix( cp ) ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
125.45
987.65
100.00
99.99
```

Comment: strtok() is on my forbidden list, but I think you've got the right idea - manual string substitution is the simplest solution with the least amount of code rewrite.

Comment: @Piers You can use `strpbrk( )` or `strspn()` or even `strchr()` to "lightly touch" the source string, but that involves a bit of pointer arithmetic and copying that can be prone to "off by one" hassles... Glad this at least helps you get started with minimal changes to code. `:-)`